# How to fetch 3 million records from database and generate CSV files

Tags: java, multithreading

I have 3 million records in the database. I want to fetch and create multiple csv files. Each csv file should have 0.2 million records. How can achieve this requirement in a faster way? How can we  achieve it using Multi-threading?

Comment: What DB are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use several threads that do this for you I would use `OFFSET` and several queries (15 to be exact (3M/200K)).

The first problem is creating the queries. This would be one way:

```java
int offset = 0;
int incrementer = 200000; // 200k
String baseQuery = "SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... LIMIT 200000 OFFSET "; // OFFSET must be supported by your DB for this to work.

ArrayList<String> queries = new ArrayList<>();

int queryCount = 3000000 / incrementer;

for (int i = 0; i < queryCount; i++) 
{
    String tmpQuery = baseQuery + offset;
    offset += incrementer;
    
    queries.add(tmpQuery);
}
```

Now we got our queries. We should create a thread for each of them, where they will fetch the data and create your CSV files.

```java
for (String query : queries)
{
    Runnable runnable = () ->
    {
        // Use preparedStatement to create the query
        // Fetch the data
        // Write them to cv file
        
        // use query variable!
    };
    
    Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
    thread.start();

}
```

Still, don't expect a performance increase from this, all the threads read from the same (DB) disk, and that requires time.

Comment: I think you are missing a limit.

Comment: Good find! Thank you @ScaryWombat

Comment: 2000000; // 200k  ;it is 2000k right.can we create multi threads and create tasks to fetch the data from above DB query?

Comment: @user739115 there was one `0` too much, I removed it. Yes, the code to create threads is also there.

Comment: In The first step  is creating the queries ,can we create multi threading to fetch the records from DB add it in array list?. the code that you have  written in the first step will run in single thread only right.I see in the 2dn setp you have used multiple threads.

Comment: You "create" the Queries first in **one** thread and then you start fetching the data from multiple threads.

Comment: I think this should  be LIMIT 200000 OFFSET ...

Comment: @user739115 true, a 0 too much there too. Sorry about that.